Is it a bit circular to say that every thing is equal to exactly one thing?
This is a theorem of first-order logic with equality: $(\forall x)(\exists! y)x=y$, where the $\exists!$ means the unique existential quantifier. However, this theorem seems a bit circular, or at least a bit weird. It says that every individual thing is equal to exactly one thing. But, "exactly one" is itself defined using equality. In fact, the theorem, when unabbreviated, says that something is equal to $x$, and any two things which are equal to $x$ are equal to each other. So, can anyone explain this phenomenon to me? Basically, what I am really getting at is, can two things be equal to one another, without them actually being the exact same thing?

This is actually quite subtle. You might enjoy reading Mazur's When is one thing equal to some other thing?: https://people.math.osu.edu/cogdell.1/6112-Mazur-www.pdf

Isn't almost every theorem of first-order logic (with equality) a bit weird and not really of interest in "everyday mathematics"? For example, if a formula $\phi$ is provable then so is $\phi\land\forall x(x=x)$, but I can't imagine anyone ever wanting to assert such a statement in a context outside of mathematical logic.

"can two things be equal to one another, without them actually being the exact same thing" Yes, this can happen in intensional type theory for example. This is how you end up with richer notions of equality, like in homotopy type theory. I wouldn't call your theorem "weird", but maybe something more like "fundamental". It is also known as the contractibility of singletons.

When the philosophical community came to the conclusion that distance was an illusion and all places were in fact the same place, Ly Tin Wheedle was the philosopher to make the famed conclusion that "Although all places were in fact the same place, that place was very big".
